# Opencart redirect defined routes

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm have couple of not used routes and searching for solutions to redirect this routes.

For example I have `['common/cart','affiliate/edit' ]`

array of routes, and where I can add check to check If route is in this array redirect to 404 ? I think that can be done in `/controller/common/seo_url.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places where you can add your redirection conditions, the most important thing is avoiding changing the code of core libraries, so I think that the best place would be in `index.php`

- Open the file `<OC_ROOT>/index.php`
- Search for this code fragment:

```php
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}
```

- In the `isset` part, you can check if the variable `$request->get['route']` matches any of your obsolete routes and redirect on that basis, for example:

```php
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $ignored_routes = array('common/cart', 'affiliate/edit');
    if(in_array($request->get['route'], $ignored_routes))
        $action = new Action("error/not_found");
    else
        $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}
```

---

***P.S:*** *Your assumption is wrong, you can't do it in the file `/controller/common/seo_url.php`, what you want is `<OC_ROOT>/system/engine/action.php` ;)*